# CASE WHEN statement with non existing column ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `SELECT` statement with a few joins. In one of the joined tables I have a field with type `NVARCHAR2(1 char)`. The `NVARCHAR2(1 char)` field is `mn.TYPE` and it cannot take the case when values. How can I save these values in a non existing column? Below is the select:

```
select 
        DISTINCT (mn.guid), 
        rg.ID, 
        mn.description, 
        rg.name, 
        nvl(riq.IS_IR, 0),
        mn.TYPE,
  case mn.TYPE
    when 'S'
        then 'Standard'
    when 'L'
        then 'Local'
    when 'C'
        then 'Pfp'
    else
        mn.TYPE
    end 
from red_survey_groups rg
join surveys s on rg.ID = s.RED_SURVEY_GROUP_ID and s.IS_RED = 1 and s.SUPPRESSED = 0
join measure_nodes mn on s.ID = mn.SURVEY_ID and mn.OWNER_ID is not null
left join red_ir_questions riq on rg.ID = riq.SURVEY_GROUP_ID and riq.QUESTION_ID = mn.GUID
order by rg.NAME,mn.TYPE desc,mn.GUID;
```

Answer (score 1):

It works, only if you know how. Check the difference between your and my `CASE` syntax.

```
SQL> create table measure_nodes (type nvarchar2(1));

Table created.

SQL> insert into measure_nodes values ('S');

1 row created.
```

You:

```
SQL> select case mn.type when 'S' then 'standard' end from measure_nodes mn;
select case mn.type when 'S' then 'standard' end from measure_nodes mn
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12704: character set mismatch
```

Me:

```
SQL> select case when mn.type = 'S' then 'standard' end from measure_nodes mn;

CASEWHEN
--------
standard

SQL>
```

---

Aha; as of joins and stuff, would `CAST` or `TRANSLATE` do any good?

```
SQL> select d.dname,
  2        case when mn.type = 'S' then 'standard' else cast(mn.type as varchar2(1)) end as mn_type
  3  from measure_nodes mn cross join dept d;

DNAME          MN_TYPE
-------------- --------
ACCOUNTING     standard
RESEARCH       standard
SALES          standard
OPERATIONS     standard

SQL>
SQL> select d.dname,
  2        case when mn.type = 'S' then translate('standard' using nchar_cs) else mn.type  end as mn_type
  3  from measure_nodes mn cross join dept d;

DNAME          MN_TYPE
-------------- --------
ACCOUNTING     standard
RESEARCH       standard
SALES          standard
OPERATIONS     standard

SQL>
```

Comment: what happens with the joins below since i am selecting from a different table than the measure_nodes mn, that table is only included in the joins and "end from measure_nodes mn" does not work unfortunately.

Comment: I posted some more info; have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [NVARCHAR2 Literal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm) e.g.  `N'S'`

This works fine

```
 case mn.type when  N'S' then  N'standard' else mn.type end
```

As mentioned in other answer without the `N` you get `ORA-12704: character set mismatch` which is expected as the column has `NVARCHAR2` characted set and the literal the database charset.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [national character set literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA) rather than an ordinary text literal for the comparison and return value in the `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       mn.guid,
       rg.ID, 
       mn.description, 
       rg.name, 
       nvl(riq.IS_IR, 0),
       mn.TYPE,
       case mn.TYPE
       WHEN n'S' THEN n'Standard'
       WHEN n'L' THEN n'Local'
       WHEN n'C' THEN n'Pfp'
       ELSE mn.TYPE
       END 
FROM   red_survey_groups rg
       join surveys s
       on rg.ID = s.RED_SURVEY_GROUP_ID and s.IS_RED = 1 and s.SUPPRESSED = 0
       join measure_nodes mn
       on s.ID = mn.SURVEY_ID and mn.OWNER_ID is not null
       left join red_ir_questions riq
       on rg.ID = riq.SURVEY_GROUP_ID and riq.QUESTION_ID = mn.GUID
order by rg.NAME,mn.TYPE desc,mn.GUID;
```

*(Note: `DISTINCT` is a keyword that applies to **ALL** columns being returned; it is not a function that applies to just one column.)*